# If speeds of two cars are Normal RV s, what is the distribution of the distance between them?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

The speeds of two cars are random variables that follow $N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$ and $N(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$ distributions.They start simultaneously. Let X be the distance between them after m hours. (Note that it's distance between and so either car may be ahead of the other.) Find:

(i) P$(X<a)$
(ii)P$(X=a)$

for any real number $a\geq 0$.

Comment: Answer: (i) What have you tried? (ii) What are your difficulties?

Comment: I can't figure out even what the distribution of the distance between will be. For that, we need the distributions of the individual distances, but all we know is that the speeds are normal variables. I initially tried integration but there's a lot of confusion about the function as well. Any help is appreciated, especially if it has a road to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $N_1\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $N_2\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ the respective speeds of cars 1 and 2.

I will assume in the following that $N_1$ and $N_2$ are independent, and that both cars start at the same point.

After $m$ hours, the first car will be at a distance $mN_1$ from the origin and the second car will be at a distance $mN_2$ from the origin. Note that $N_1$ or $N_2$ may be negative, i.e. the cars may be going in opposite directions.

Either way, the distance between both cars is $X=m\left|N_1-N_2\right|$.

Now, do you know what the distribution of $N_1-N_2$ is? If not, look at the characteristic function, and use the independence of $N_1$ and $N_2$.